# readline emacs equivalent to vi's 'fc'

Tags: emacs, vi, readline

In vi readline, I can use the command `fc` where c is a character I want to find and jump to in the current line. E.g.

```
echo 'hello world'
fw -------->
```

Is there an equivalent command in emacs mode?  The closest I have seen it `C-]` but I'm looking specifically for `fc`.

Comment: What wrong with `C-]c`?  It seems to behave just like `fc`.

Comment: I just tried this in the [JuliaLang](https://github.com/JuliaLang/readline) shell and it didn't work, but it did on a Bash shell.  I guess not all shells are equal.

Comment: Which version are you using?  They dropped GNU readline in favor of their own implementation for REPL line edit in [v0.3](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md#julia-v030-release-notes).

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  I'm using  Julia Version 0.4.0-dev+6930 (2015-08-24 09:35 UTC

Comment: Good to see that people understand that bash readline is not the first and only implementation. There is e.g. the history editor that I prototyped in 1982 and implemented finally for my bsh in 1984 and added in 2006 to the Bourne shell and there is ksh from 1984. There is a recent BSD implementation...